# Push down the footer as content grows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these two illustration for the issue I need to fix:

1. Footer is relative and pushed down as textarea grows, but there is a
   whitespace below the footer

[image]

2. Footer is absoluted and is just right in the bottom of the page but it is not pushed down as content (textarea) grows

[image]

The code for the footer & content is:

```
.content {
    padding-bottom: 124px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height:124px !important;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative !important;
    bottom: 0px; !important;
    left: 0px;
}
```

The question is how can I make that the footer stays at the bottom even when the content is not full, while as content grows it should be pushed down further.

Comment: Put the footer *inside* the content div.

Comment: Rory, Then the footer wont be at the bottom when content area is small.

Comment: You said the footer position was absolute but your code shows relative?

Comment: @Timo yes, I tried both position: relative and position: absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the sticky footer solution from http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

> ```
> * {
>     margin: 0;
> }
>
> html, body {
>     height: 100%;
> }
>
> .wrapper {
>     min-height: 100%;
>     height: auto !important;
>     height: 100%;
>     .margin: 0 auto -4em;
> }
>
> .footer, .push {
>     height: 4em;
> }
> ```

with HTML

> ```
> ...
> <body>
>     <div class="wrapper">
>         <p>Your website content here.</p>
>         <div class="push"></div>
>
>     </div>
>     <div class="footer">
>         Content of footer
>     </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

The only limitation is that you have to know the size of **the footer**

Answer (score 0):

apply

```
overflow: auto;
```

to the `content`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `calc` trick that isn't so obtuous and very simple to work with, it only works in IE9 and up, though, and it requires you to know the size of your footer as well. I have added `%` values as well to have some semblance of logic for older browsers. This will also allow the content to expand as much as it wants.

```css
html, body { 
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#content, #footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: whiteSmoke;
}
#content {
  min-height: 90%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
#footer {
  height: 10%;
  height: calc(100px);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```