# Get delta of textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to adjust the total height of the page as the textarea grows. For the reason that the page have a footer with `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` the textarea overflows with the footer (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938831/push-down-the-footer-as-content-grows) for details).

After juggling with so many CSS codes to try to fix the issue, I am thinking of just monitoring the delta of the textarea with jQuery and just add it to the total height of the page or minus if the delta is negative.

For this reason, is there a way to

- Observe the delta of a textarea with jQuery?
- And add or minus that delta to the overall height of the page?

Comment: i'm sorry, but what is a "delta" may i ask?

Comment: He means the different size it gets as it grows with contents I think. Also, if your elements _aren't_ absolute then you could just grow the textarea and everything would push nicely...

Comment: @xybrek it seems like a bad idea to have a footer with `position: absolute`, there are many better ways to solve it not the least both good answers you got from your previous question.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle showcasing the issue?